# How do I see leaves with children as parents in TreeView asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Hello and thank you in advance.

I am working on a website that has a Tree View Menu when navigated to sub-pages of the main site. The problem here is that everything works fine when navigating to the parent and child portion, but when I click on the leaves it remains to not show the title of the child above the leaves. I will show you what I mean down below in the photos but I can navigate fine to the parent and children but when a leaf (the hierarchical node below the child...) it does not show the child of the leaves.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVcJF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtSyp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPAdt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKUwf.png)

So it means I need assistance on the last part of the structure... Which is the page (and nav) that contains the "Overview" section. It needs to display the node above it hierarchically.

Thank you in advance...

I appreciate it,

CR8TIVE

As of right now I am using the properties listed below for the Tree View and SiteMapDataSource...

TreeView

- ExpandDepth="2"
- MaxDataBindDepth="1"

SiteMapDataSource

- StartFromCurrentNode="True"
- StartingNodeOffset="0"

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try increasing the ExpandDepth to 3 or 4 but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Gave it a try and no luck so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.